# Attribute routing and RouteLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I Define My **Home View** like

```
<body>
    <div> 
        <h1>Home</h1>
        @Html.RouteLink("R1", "first", new { user="R1"})
        @Html.RouteLink("R2", "second", new { company = "R2" })
    </div>
</body>
```

and **login controller** like

```
public class LoginController : Controller
   {
       // GET: Login

      [Route("{user}", Name = "first")]
       public ActionResult Index(string user)
       {
           return View();
       }
      [Route("{company}", Name = "second")]
      public ActionResult Index2(string company)
      {
          return View();
      }
   }
```

**RouteConfig**

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


        }
    }
```

I imagine on home page **R1** and **R2** click its routed to correct action result Index and Index2 respectively .

But its generate bellow error

> The current request is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String) on type
>   MVCTest.Controllers.LoginController System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Index2(System.String) on type MVCTest.Controllers.LoginController

I have no Idea why this happen.

Comment: I know you are busy person and have some problems with `routes` consider looking in my answer to solve the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** Because you only specify `{params}` in your route the request will be to `www.example.con/params` and the program it's **confused** because you have **2 actions** with this url, and **that's why the error.**

```
www.example.con/matrixwebtech // Login/Index/matrixwebtech or Login/Index2/matrixwebtech? 
www.example.con/stackoverflow // Login/Index/stackoverflowor Login/Index2/stackoverflow?
```

---

**Solution:** As you see there is no difference between this 2 routes, we have to make one.

To **solve** this you have to make the routes distinct `name/{params}` not only `{params}`.

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    [Route("{user}", Name = "first")]
    public ActionResult Index(string user)
    {
        return View();
    }
    [Route("company/{company}", Name = "second")]
    public ActionResult Index2(string company)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

To access this now we will have this routes with **no confussion**

```
www.example.con/matrixwebtech // /Login/Index/matrixwebtech
www.example.con/company/stackoverflow // /Login/Index2/stackoverflow
```

**Note:** You can find more info about [`Route` here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx)

Comment: Hi,yesterday  read the article. and facing problem.please read above comments where I discuss about nopcommerc.

Comment: @matrixwebtech i looked on that, but there is **only 1 action** that do just 1 thing **displaing a product**. You try to acces **2 actions** with same address, this can be compared with trying to access www.stackoverlfow.com and expecting to see Google instead...

Comment: @matrixwebtech To do what you show, you need **only 1 action** to be on route `/`. You have to choose, see my update answer where i choose `user` to be on `/`.

Comment: the thing is not very clear to me , 
so its not done by attribute routing,I have to do this by convetion-based routing.Right? can you please give me some idea.how do I do this,a sample or tutorial link is appreciated

Comment: @matrixwebtech What you want it's called *slug url* you can find this all over the internet, it can be done with attribute routing or wihout them, it's dosen't really matter. The action is one that matter. [See here](http://www.namedquery.com/implement-url-slugs-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using *{user}* an *{company}*, use *user* and *company*

Example:

```
    [Route("user", Name = "first")]
    public ActionResult Index(string user)
    {
        return View();
    }
    [Route("company", Name = "second")]
    public ActionResult Index2(string company)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply if I use  `[Route("user", Name = "first")]` the url is **/user?user=R1** and if use ` [Route("login/index/{user}", Name = "first")] `then the url is **/login/index/R1** but I don't want url like these .If you go to [link]http://demo.nopcommerce.com[/link] on home page on left **category** menu click on **Electronics ** and also click on **$25 Virtual Gift Card** product for 1st the url is [link]http://demo.nopcommerce.com/electronics[/link] and for 2nd [link]demo.nopcommerce.com/build-your-own-computer[\link] ,I think they also routed to different route .how the do this?

Comment: So you want to show only user and company? like this?  localhost:1234/user/R1

Comment: localhost:1234/user/R1 this is fine but I dont know is it possible or not? can I show  localhost:1234/R1 or some thing and program will know which action to be called .you can see the nopcommece website.

Comment: Yes it's possible. But you will need to add additional (more specific routes in route config)

Comment: so its not done by attribute routing,I have to do this by convetion-based routing.Right? can you please give me some idea.how do I do this,a sample or tutorial link is appreciated.